# What is the chance of the whole atmosphere vanishing?

Tags: climate, science-in-society

So in my science class I have been studying Green House Gases and I have learned that the atmosphere is beginning to have holes, which then expose the sunlight from coming in. I am just wondering if it's possible for the whole atmosphere to vanish and whether it is possible that we are able to still live on our Earth.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Nova*! I am quite sure what you mean with the "expose the sunlight from coming in." part. Did you mean "prevent" as in "sunlight doesn't get through the atmosphere"? This doesn't quite seem to align with the rest of your post. Or maybe that the holes are "allowing" the sunlight to directly get to the Earth? It would be nice if you could [edit] your qestion to explain this part. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: You might also be interested in this question on our sister site EarthScience.SE [Does the Antarctic Ozone Hole affect the rest of the world?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9528) and this question on our sister site Physics.SE [Ozone Hole in the South Pole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9088/143503)

Comment: The atmosphere cannot have holes -- you cannot have a hole in a gas. Some *layers* of the atmosphere have discontinuities, some of longer duration, some of shorter duration. The discontinuities (a.k.a. "holes") in the ozone layer allow more ultraviolet rays to reach the surface.

Comment: By "what is the chance" you mean what exactly? Do you want to know if this is actually going to happen or do you want to know how this could happen for example in a science fiction movie? You should also specify a time frame, are you interested in *eventually*, talking billions of years here, or if this will happen this year?

Comment: So you learned about [the hole in the ozone layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_layer). This is not a matter of the **atmosphere** disappearing. It is the matter of **one constituent** of the atmosphere not being there **in its previous form**. The atoms that make up the Ozone (O3... 3 oxygen atoms per 1 ozone molecule) have not disappeared, they have just been converted to molecular oxygen (O2). Hence 2 Ozone molecules becomes 3 Oxygen molecules. So your question is moot: the atmosphere does not "disappear" or "have holes".

Answer (score 1):

The chances are the same of a space body passing near the Earth with enough gravitational actraction to suck all the gas but nothing else (also if it probably will change Earth's orbit). I don't think that there are many chances, but I have no data on hands.

For the second part of your question, probably also all the water will vanish since it is liquid at this temperature and pressure: if you lower the pressure, the boiling point temperature of water is lower (classic school experiment).

With air and water gone, we cannot live in Earth more than we can on the Moon or Mars, using the same technologies we should use on them.
Other life forms probably will disappear, excluded perhaps some bacteria that can adapt to such extreme condition

Comment: So if the water starts evaporating, it will form a new atmosphere. Are you sure that the water will vanish, or, for starters, no liquid water will exist anymore?

Comment: @Raditz_35 true, but also this new athmosphere will be sucked away by the same object that sucked away the "old" atmosphere. Maybe some trace of water will exist, but I don't think in liquid form if the pressure drop under a certain level

Comment: But then you agree that your argumentation for why the water is vanishing is incorrect. Btw could you maybe go into a bit more detail how this passing of such a massive object might work? I don't think this is the best bet for a vanishing atmosphere anyhow, but you should maybe state how massive, how close, for how long, how will it alter earth's orbit, how can such an object even get close to earth and so on. Just from your answer, I have no idea how you picture the scenario = it raises more questions than it answers

Comment: No, I don't agree. The water became vapor and the vapor will sucked away. Of course the reason the gasses are sucked away from Earth must be still here.  For the object I have no hard data, but an idea is that a planet/object enter in a somewhat stable orbit around the Earth and have the necessary attraction to rip off the gasses, without (or with little) other collateral damages.

Comment: "For the second part of your question, probably also all the water will vanish since it is liquid at this temperature and pressure: if you lower the pressure, the boiling point temperature of water is lower (classic school experiment)." is not the same as saying " The water became vapor and the vapor will sucked away."

Comment: Ok, I should learn English a little better than :-( All I want to say is that the water, from a Earth point of view, will vanish since it evaporate and then is sucked away. I use "vanish" as a synonymous of "disappear"

Answer (score 1):

The atmosphere does not have holes in it. Some gases are not evenly spread, but the atmosphere is still present.

If the atmosphere did vanish, we would all die pretty quickly, most immediately, others because they run out of resources. Most life if not all on earth would succumb pretty quickly.